# How can I improve this design to achieve a more loosely coupled system and better testability?

Tags: design, object-oriented, c++, uml, solid

## My question

I built an [inverted pendulum](https://5.imimg.com/data5/DJ/QN/MY-931948/direct-drive-inverted-pendulum-system-500x500.jpg) on an Arduino using C (ie. everything was done procedurally). I'm trying to self study application design and would like to refactor my code into a more OO approach with SOLID, loose coupling, and testability in mind.

**How can I improve this design to achieve a more loosely coupled system and better testability?**

## UML

[image: UML-class-diagram]

## Brief summary of classes

`MotorController` - An interface for motor controllers.

`DrokL928` - Is the motor controller I use, implements `MotorController`.

`Cart` - Is just a convenient wrapper for `DrokL928`. Allows for more intuitive control of the cart.

`Encoder` - An external library for reading values from rotary encoders.

`EncoderWrapper` - A wrapper for `Encoder`. That way I encapsulate the external API into one place.

`StateVector` - Holds the current state data.

`StateUpdater` - Processes encoder values from `EncoderWrapper` and assigns them to `StateVector`.

`LQRController` - Computes the PWM signal (based on the current state) to send to the Cart in order to stabilize the pendulum. see: [Wikipedia's linear-quadratic-regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator).

## Specific design questions

1. `StateUpdater` uses constants `IDLER_PULLEY_RADIUS` and `SYSTEM_LOOP_RATE`. These smell like they don't belong inside `StateUpdater`, but they are relevant to the calculation of the state. I suppose all of those private methods inside `StateUpdater` could be put into a separate class `StateCalculator`?
2. `LQRController` uses the constant `pendulumBound`. That is, the LQR controller should only calculate the input if the pendulum angle is within a certain bound. For some reason I feel like this doesn't belong here, but maybe I'm wrong on that. For the sake of completeness, maybe I should add a bound for each variable in `StateVector`.
3. As of right now I can't instantiate `EncoderWrapper` into a test harness because it requires a reference to an `Encoder`. And by extension, I can't instantiate a `StateUpdater` into a test harness. How can I fix this?
4. In the most ideal case, I would like for `StateVector` to not be so hardcoded and the variables should be open to modification. Therefore, `LQRController` should have a `gainVector` of any length (right now it is hardcoded to 4). Is this too much abstraction? If not, how can I go about achieving this? Now that I think about it, I believe it would be too much abstraction because then I'm not sure how the `StateUpdater` would calculate the state on arbitrary state variables, because the algorithm is very specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the hallmarks of good design is that it is mostly self-explanatory, even to someone without much knowledge about the domain. It so happens that I had no idea what an inverted pendulum was before reading your question, so I tried to gather some insights from your diagram, but unfortunately `Cart` seemed to be the only object that was possibly related to your problem domain.

After quickly reading about [inverted pendulums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum) on Wikipedia, the details of your design started to make more sense but then I realized that you were missing abstractions such as `Pendulum`, and instead had the state and behavior scattered between `StateVector` and `StateUpdater`.

My suggestion would be to **think about your system outside-in and focus on the concepts you are trying to model rather than how they are implemented.** For example, you mentioned:

> `Cart` - Is just a convenient wrapper for `DrokL928`. Allows for more intuitive control of the cart.

`Cart` isn't just a "convenient wrapper", it is one of the primary things you are trying to model. A cart has a position and velocity, and its movement can be controlled. `Encoder` and `MotorController` are implementation details used to obtain the current state and control the movement, respectively.

Similarly, you would have a `Pendulum` class with angle and velocity properties, again using an `Encoder` internally to obtain these values.

And finally, an `InvertedPendulum` class that represents the entire system consisting of a `Cart` and a `Pendulum`, and uses a `Controller` to stabilize the system.

This eliminates `StateVector` and `StateUpdater` from your design since all the pieces have been moved into more meaningful objects.

> As of right now I can't instantiate `EncoderWrapper` into a test harness because it requires a reference to an `Encoder`. ... How can I fix this?

By creating an interface just like you did for `MotorController`. The real implementation will call the external library, and you can create one or more fake implementations that will simply return canned responses for your tests.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for this answer it was extremely helpful. One question I have is how do I handle the onion-style class creation? Specifically, `Cart` requires an `EncoderWrapper` which requires an `Encoder`. So it would essentially look like ```Cart(new EncoderWrapper(new Encoder))```. Is this good practice? Should I be handling this in a different way?

Comment: @Hunter: Yes, you've basically described [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), which is considered a best practice. For an embedded system such as yours, you can probably just do it by hand in your `main` function. In larger applications, you might use a DI framework.

Comment: Would you be able to clarify what you mean when you say "by hand"? I planned on doing something like `Encoder = ...; EncoderWrapper = ....; Cart(EncoderWrapper);`. That is, instantiate each object and then pass them in where needed, instead of doing it all inside the constructor in one-go like in my first comment.

Comment: "By hand" simply means you're writing the instantiation code manually, and what you've described is totally fine. I was just trying to point out that there also exist libraries to aid in wiring up application components, but that's probably overkill for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full-fledged answer. But since you are designing an embedded system (and by coincidence I just worked on an Arduino supported pendulum): These are usually large state machines. The class design is rather trivial since the controllers have anyway similar interfaces. So that's the minor part. The big one is the desgin of the state machine. And of course since you are dealing with a real-time application you will find that you can not always follow the gods of good design in favor of needed performance :-/

Regaring test: This is especially tricky for RT applications. By adding test you distort the behavior of the system. E.g. I added a fast buffer logger that could eventually be read post mortem. Doing fancy debugging is simply not possible since physics does not allow to stop motion when you want to look at it.

Comment: How much does changing the structure from C to C++ change the performance? Is there a way I can measure that? Also, this isn't a state machine. My system stabilizes the pendulum using an LQR controller, so there is in fact separate objects with their own responsibilities. Lastly, I wouldn't be running tests during the real time scenario, I would create fake classes for things like `Encoder` and use that to test locally on my computer.

Comment: Changing between C and C++ would not really affect pure calculation performance. It's just that C++ can create objects from language constructs. You can simply measure performance using the HW clock. Simulation is fine, but be warned that reality _is_ different. Reacting on sensors can be time critical and influence from an inert motor might give you other head aches.